# Errno 13 Musescore 3 outputting score png through python

Tags: python, permissions, errno

I've been bashing my head against a wall for 2 days. Trying to get a png output of a music score.   I was doing it successfully using show("lily") until I came across bars with only rests (no notes) where it'd refuse to output a png.

I'm now trying to show("musicxml.png") but run into a permission error.  I've run chmod 777 and sudo chown root:wheel . /Applications/MuseScore\ 3.app, but the no joy! Any insight would be great.

(running MacOS)

```
from music21 import *


us = environment.UserSettings()

us['musicxmlPath'] = '/Applications/MuseScore 3.app'
us['musescoreDirectPNGPath'] = '/Applications/MuseScore 3.app'
s = stream.Stream()
s.append(note.Rest())
s.show("musicxml.png")
```

traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/personal_learning/check_music21.py", line 10, in

```
s.show("musicxml.png")
```

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/stream/base.py", line 334, in show
return super().show(fmt=fmt, app=app, **keywords)

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/base.py", line 2788, in show
return formatWriter.show(self,

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/subConverters.py", line 1108, in show
returnedFilePath = self.write(obj, fmt, subformats=subformats, **keywords)

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/subConverters.py", line 1091, in write
outFp = self.runThroughMusescore(xmlFp, subformats, **keywords)

File "/Users/brien/Documents/FinalProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/subConverters.py", line 964, in runThroughMusescore
completed_process = subprocess.run(musescoreRun, capture_output=True, check=False)

File "/Users/brien/micromamba/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

File "/Users/brien/micromamba/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,

File "/Users/brien/micromamba/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Applications/MuseScore 3.app'

```
ls -l . /Applications
```

drwxrwxrwx@  3 root       wheel   96  8 Feb  2021 MuseScore 3.app

Comment: Is it mis-reporting the error slightly and it's "musicxml.png" that needs chmodding, or the directory in which it sits (or will sit)?  I would 'chmod 666' the file and 'chmod 777' the directory and see if it makes a difference.  You might have tried that already though!

Comment: Hi, thanks but I've tried both of these chmod commands and no joy already.  You may be right about the the musicxml.png or the directory it's going to not having the write permissions.. just need to figure out where that is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you.  The problem is that your path `/Applications/MuseScore 3.app` is fact a folder.

`music21` environment is waiting for an executable, so your path should be: `/Applications/MuseScore 3.app/Contents/MacOS/mscore`.

Use **Finder** and right-click on your application name then **Show Package Contents**.

This worked in my case.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: This project is long since done (university final project) but I tried your solution and it worked! Nice one!